# How to extract sub-string in format hh:mm:ss.sssz from any string?

Tags: c#

For example I have string (not fix size)

```
"mynewtime10:20:13.458atcertainplace"    
"hertimeatthatplace11:20:55.12nocomment"
```

The time is at different position (index) from one string to another.

Comment: Show the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code hope it will work.

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string str = "mynewtime10:20:13.458atcertainplace";
        string patt = @"([0-9:.]+)";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(patt, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(str);
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", str, matches.Count);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
                Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
        }
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using following regex?

```
([0-9:.]+)
```

Your searched string is in group 1